# React unzip from dropZone

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, unzip

I want to drag n drop and upload a zip file and then unzip that file in a specific folder and if that folder doesnt exist should create it. I have used react DropZone and im at this stage so far. Any ideas how do i proceed with accepting only zip files and upload to a certain folder?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link'
import Head from '../components/head'
import Nav from '../components/nav'
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone'

export default class DnD extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      accepted: [],
      rejected: []
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <div className="dropzone">
          <Dropzone
            accept="image/jpeg, image/png"
            onDrop={(accepted, rejected) => { this.setState({ accepted, rejected }); }}
          >
            <p>Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.</p>
            <p>Only *.jpg and *.png images will be accepted</p>
          </Dropzone>
        </div>
        <aside>
          <h2>Accepted files</h2>
          <ul>
            {
              this.state.accepted.map(f => <li key={f.name}>{f.name} - {f.size} bytes</li>)
            }
          </ul>
          <h2>Rejected files</h2>
          <ul>
            {
              this.state.rejected.map(f => <li key={f.name}>{f.name} - {f.size} bytes</li>)
            }
          </ul>
        </aside>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
<DnD />
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'upload to a certain folder' if you want to upload it to your server you should upload the zip file then unzip it server side.

Comment: Thats exactly what i meant. Upload it to my server in specific folder and unzip it on server side, if i knew the approach i would do that but thats why i ve asked. Thanks for the info tho